# how to select and sum in single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible or another solution to sum and select multiple rows in single sql query and print with while looping like that:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Total), * FROM table");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    echo $fetch[a];
    echo $fetch[b];
    echo $fetch[c];
}
```

Comment: do you mean `running total`?

Comment: if not, try this, `SELECT (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM table) totalSum, a.* FROM \`table\` a`

Comment: i want to sum and select all table in rows

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM `table`) totalSum, a.* FROM `table` a
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a JOIN with a subquery that calculates the total.

```
SELECT SumTotal, a.*
FROM Table a
JOIN (SELECT SUM(Total) SumTotal
      FROM Table) b
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it as what @491243 suggested

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM `table`) AS totalSum, * FROM `table`
```

But this is not recommended because this will cause that `SQL Engine` calculate `sum` of the column `total` on each row it's selecting from the database and sending a new column with the results to `php` with identical values in the column `totalSum` fields ,

better go for 2 queries.
one for selecting the rows and the other to get the total

Answer (score 1):

We can use CROSS APPLY for calculation.

```
SELECT SumTotal, A.* 
FROM table A 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Total) SumTotal FROM Table) B
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **GROUP BY** clause.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *,SUM(Total) as TotalSUM FROM table GROUP BY Total");

    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {

    echo $fetch[a];
    echo $fetch[b];
    echo $fetch[c];


    }
```

Comment: Wrong!! this will return 1 row

Comment: Changed to GROUP BY instead of ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to group by a column so that you can sum by a group and then it will give you separate rows for each category_id in this example

```
SELECT category_id, SUM(price) as totalprice
FROM products 
GROUP BY category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it simpler and faster to sum inside the loop instead using complex query ?

you could just make simple (faster) `select * from table` and in your `while` loop make the sum while looping. it will be faster than making query with subquery